# vibration of Edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

i want to create a edit text that will vibrate if given input is invalid.
for example edit text for number if number is wrong like it contain 9 digits than edit text will became clear and will vibrate for some time
how to create that?
 thanks in advance

Comment: Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) ; i used this bt it's not working

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Create anim folder in resources and then create file named shake.xml
and paste the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="10" android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@anim/cycle_7" />
```

and another file cycle_7.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cycleInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:cycles="7" />
```

and then in your java file

```
if(invalid)//check your input
{
   Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Login.this, R.anim.shake);
   editText.startAnimation(shake);
}
```

Answer (score 27):

If anyone is looking for a method to do what @[Priya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1900651/priya) suggested programatically, then you can try this.

```
public TranslateAnimation shakeError() {
        TranslateAnimation shake = new TranslateAnimation(0, 10, 0, 0);
        shake.setDuration(500);
        shake.setInterpolator(new CycleInterpolator(7));
        return shake;
}
```

And then:

```
myEditText.startAnimation(shakeError());
```

Comment: This feels more clean compared to the XML one.

Answer (score 5):

For vibrate use the following code.

```
Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

Then, in the OnTextChanged Listener method use the following code.

```
vibe.vibrate(50); // 50 is time in ms
```

And don't forget you need to add the permission to the manifest (after the `</application>` tag):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Create `shake.xml` under anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-10"
        android:toXDelta="10"
        android:repeatCount="5"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:duration="70" />
</set>
```

After this add animation for button. I wrote this code in Kotlin for simplicity.

```
button.setOnClickListener {
      button.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.shake)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this listener to EditText for your desired validation,

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new  TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Write your logic here
                    if(condition satisfy)
                    // call vibrate();  
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });



        public void vibrate()
        {
                Vibrator vibrate= (Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) ;
                           vibrate.vibrate(50);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is code for Kotlin

```
private fun vibrator() {
    vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator?
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        vibrator!!.vibrate(
            VibrationEffect.createOneShot(
                500,
                VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE
            )
        )
    } else {
        //deprecated in API 26
        vibrator!!.vibrate(500)
    }
}
```